# Using JS to control isset post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was wondering if there was a way by which we can control a form submit with js. Basically checking a condition with js before submitting a form.

for the php part to be something like-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//some code
}
else{
//some code
}
```

and the js part to be something like -

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var a(say) = something;
  var b = something;
  if(a>b){
    alert("cannot be submitted")
    //code to not submit the form
  }
  else{
    //code to proceed to submit
    //or 
    //no code if not required
  }
```

If possible i'd like to have the code in this format as much as it can be. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `return false` for not submitting form in `if` condition of click event

Comment: @bharatparmar tried it, still gets submitted

Comment: You can use type="button" instead of type="submit" in button and then use $("#formId").submit(); in JS to submit form in else part

Comment: Yes, you can use preventDefault() inside your submit handler method and then use the if condition for submit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Check your statements in javascript like above and if you're satisfied, send a `XMLHttpRequest();` to php;

example:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var a(say) = something;
  var b = something;
  if(a>b){
    alert("oops, something went wrong here...");
  }
  else{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var data = "this is important data to send to the server";

    xhr.open("POST", "url.php");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(data);
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain what this ```xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");``` means?

Comment: That is required, when you send data with the ```POST``` method. If you're sending data with the ```GET``` method, you have to send the values through the link so it is not required. More details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Comment: also the ```"url.php"``` in ```xhr.open("POST", "url.php");``` is the php file that is supposed to be in the ```action=""``` in my form right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So it is the path to your php file

Comment: the ```action``` field had no path to any php file, so should i just keep it as blank? i was given this project to add a functionality to it so im not sure how the POST is actually working here.

Comment: It makes rather little sense to use the native XMLHttpRequest object, if jQuery is in use already …

Comment: @misorude is totally right! I havent coded with jquery a long time ago. Sorry, my bad. I really tried to help.